ACF show repeater rows in sets
I have a FAQ section with 15 questions. I want to show the first 8 questions grouped. Then display the remaining question in another group. I have code for the first set already. I'm not sure how to display the remaining rows. I tried something like this.
<?php
if( have_rows('faq', 'options') ):
    $i = 5;
    while ( have_rows('faq', 'options') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php if( $i > 12 ): ?>
            <?php break; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>   
                            <div class="accordion-item faq-item">
                                <h2 class="faq-header" id="flush-heading<?php the_sub_field('flush'); ?>">
                                <button class="accordion-button faq-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapse<?php the_sub_field('flush'); ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapse<?php the_sub_field('flush'); ?>">
                                    <?php the_sub_field('question'); ?>
                                </button>
                                </h2>
                                <div id="flush-collapse<?php the_sub_field('flush'); ?>" class="accordion-collapse collapse faq-collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingSix" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                                    <div align="left" class="faq-item-body">
                                        <p><?php the_sub_field('answer'); ?></p> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
<?php endwhile;
 
else :

endif;
?>


Here’s a general pattern that you can follow. It is a for loop, but you can hopefully adapt it to a while loop.

Thanks for the example Chris. But I'm not sure how to apply it to my current issue.  Looking at want you sent seems like it would be perfect for the issue I'm facing.

Set $i to zero instead of five. Increment $i at the end of the loop instead of the beginning. Instead of comparing against 12, compare against 8. Instead of break, just echo your new grouping tag. Outside of the loop, but before the else, closing the grouping tag,

That all said, if you want to show 8 items here and the rest elsewhere, that’s a different problem. If that’s the case then this becomes “show the first n items of an ACF/while loop” and “skip the first n items of an ACF/while loop”

you can simply do if(get_row_index() < 9) {} else {} - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_row_index/

@Snuffy, I’ve been using ACF for a long time and never knew that existed! Thanks!

Another option - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022847/wordpress-advanced-custom-fields-repeater-wrap-every-3-divs-in-a-row

@Snuffy how would I apply the get_row_index to the code above?

@ChrisHaas and Snuffy, thank you both for all your help with this.
